# Acess files in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ : React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-share

I have implement method to download pdf fro both ios and android but I'm unable to access the iOS file saved location.My implementation as follow,

```
const downloadAndSavePDFs = async () => {
    setDownloadingToDevice(true);
    const externalStorageDirectory =
      Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath
        : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;

    const imageArray = downloadImages.map((item: any) => item.image);

    const pdfContent = imageArray
      .map((base64Image: any) => `<img src=${base64Image} />`)
      .join('');

    const imageStyles = `
      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 90vh;
        object-fit: contain;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }
    `;

    const htmlContent = `
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
              <body>
                <div class="pdf-content">
                  ${pdfContent}
                </div>
              </body>
            </html>
          `;

    const options = {
      html: htmlContent,
      fileName:
        voucher.clientID.toString() + ' - ' + voucher.archiveNo.toString(),
      directory: 'Documents',
    };

    const pdfFile: any = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);

    const downloadsPath = `${externalStorageDirectory}/${
      voucher.clientID + ' - ' + voucher.archiveNo
    }.pdf`;

    try {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        await RNFS.moveFile(pdfFile.filePath, downloadsPath);
      } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
         const shareOptions = {
           title: 'Share PDF',
           message: 'Check out this PDF!',
           url: pdfFile.filePath,
           type: 'application/pdf',
         };
         await Share.open(shareOptions);
      }
      setDownloadingToDevice(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setDownloadingToDevice(false);
    }
  };
```

I want share saved pdf file in ios, Share option is working but shared file is always empty white screen. I tired to convert HTML content as base64 string but it also not working

Please help me to sort out this issue